# Should I link html pages together using html or is python(flask) better

Tags: python, html

I've always linked webpages in html but recently saw someone use python to link html pages. Is there an added benefit to linking in python/flask over html ?

Comment: What do you mean by *linking* webpages? Flask is a micro web framework, it performs an entirely different task than HTML (markup language).

Answer (score 0):

If you have template in flask application and the html link is resolved as variable obtained with [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) or some similar way - it's preferred way of doing using links because if flask view route will be modified the link in html will be modified to (automatically), hence it's more stable variant as it reduces possibility for human factor error .